# "fatal: Authentication failed for [git url]" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error while pulling or pushing in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal.

This error is showing for the past few days.

I am using Visual Studio Code in [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git/'
```

I am able to pull or push from normal terminal, but I have to use a username and token every time I do anything.

What should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: This is a super [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) (because it affects so many). A candidate for the canonical question is *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).